# How to limitate passwords between A-Z and 1-9

Tags: shell, passwords, sh

How to check that a password only contains letters from  A-Z and/or numbers from 1-9 in shell sh

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bash, you can use extended patterns.

```
if [[ $password == +([A-Z1-9]) ]]; then echo OK; fi
```

Documented  here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-_005b_005b

> When the ‘==’ and ‘!=’ operators are used, the string to the right of the operator is considered a pattern and matched according to the rules described below in [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching), as if the `extglob` shell option were enabled.

A more POSIX sh solution would be to use `case` and look for a character that does **not** match the criteria:

```
case "$password" in
    *[^A-Z1-9]*) echo "bad password" ;;
              *) echo ok ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expr` to match a string against a regular expression.

```
if [ $(expr "$string" : '[A-Z1-9]*$') != 0 ]; then
  # valid
else
  # not valid
fi;
```

`expr` outputs the number of matches, i.e. in this case the string's length when the string is OK.

The regular expression is implicitly anchored to the beginning of the string. You can prepend a `^` if you like for better readability but it's superfluous.

If you also want to accept empty strings you have to explicitly check for them because for an empty string `expr` will output `0` just like it does, when there was no match.

```
if [ $(expr "$string" : '[A-Z1-9]*$') != 0 -o -z "$string" ]; then
  # valid
else
  # not valid
fi;
```

But that would be weak passwords. For passwords you rather want to check the opposite, that they don't only contain uppercase letters and decimal digits!